# if (controller && controller.view.superview == nil) in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to create this if statement:

```
if (controller && controller.view.superview == nil)
```

in Swift.

This is what I do:

```
if controller != nil && controller!.view!!.superview != nil
```

This is how I declare controller:

```
var controller: AnyObject? = self.viewControllers[page]
```

self.viewControllers contains either NSNull() or UIViewController

Please let me know if this is the correct way to this or there is some short-cut for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a price to pay for Optionals, readability and conciseness is part of that cost. You will still crash if the controller does not have a view. Explicit unwrapping is the new evil.

Comment: `NSNull` and `nil` are different in Objective-C.  I'm not sure how Swift handles them though.

Comment: NSNull is an Objective-C class and Swift can handle it as an Objective-C class. But NSNull is mostly used because you can't store nil into arrays or dictionaries in Objective-C, and in Swift you can, so it is much less useful. It's still useful for JSON parsers.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (controller?.view!.superview == nil)
```

Comment: Nice but in Swift the parentheses are not needed, right? We do want to be true Swift.

Comment: this brings me a compile-time error: "UIView? does not have a member named 'superview'"

Comment: @ppalancica: hey, sorry i had not compiled that code, try to unwrap UIView with ! operator, I have updated answer with same